# 'New missing/unsatisfied dependencies' error with c3p0 pooling in JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) env

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, c3p0

I want to integrate `c3p0` connection pooling into `JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19)` through `Mbean` services. Googled some examples and tried to integrate it.
Here is my configuration.
Added `c3p0` jars and `module.xml` into modules dir `{JBOSS_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/com/c3p0/main`, `module.xml` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.c3p0">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.5.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

In `standalone.xml` added `c3p0` into global modules (classpath):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="com.c3p0" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
 </subsystem>
```

Added service file into `{JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/c3p0-service.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 jboss-service_7_0.xsd">
<mbean code="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource"
     name="jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/myDB">
     <attribute name="JndiName">java:jdbc/myDB</attribute>
     <attribute name="JdbcUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.com:1521:sid</attribute>
     <attribute name="DriverClass">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</attribute>
     <attribute name="User">username</attribute>
     <attribute name="Password">password</attribute>
     <attribute name="MaxPoolSize">20</attribute>
     <attribute name="AcquireRetryAttempts">0</attribute>
     <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
</mbean>
</server>
```

Putted datasource configuration separately from `standalone.xml` into `{JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/c3p0-ds.xml`, `ojdbc6.jar` placed into the same dir.

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myDB" pool-name="myDB" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.com:1521:sid</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>username</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>30</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>300</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                     <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>120000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                </datasources>
```

`web.xml`

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>
    </description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

`jboss-web.xml`

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/myDB</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

On the end of deployment I am getting error:
`New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
service jboss.mbean.service.jboss:service=Naming.create (missing) dependents: [service jboss.mbean.service."jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/myDB".create]
service jboss.mbean.service.jboss:service=Naming.start (missing) dependents: [service jboss.mbean.service."jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/myDB".start]`

I tried lots of variations of mbean 'name' attribute, but seems the problem is in dependencies... Need help what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated!

> **EDIT:** Found another approach which is described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used another solution how to add c3p0 connection pool to JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19, because  tag is not working on JBoss 7 (as I understood from [this](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2515) topic). I used Service Archive (SAR) approach.
First of all we need to add the `c3p0` module to JBoss with specified JAR's (don't remember if all JAR's are needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.c3p0">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.5.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>      
        <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Add `c3p0` global module to `standalone.xml` (like in question section). 
Add dataSource to `standalone.xml`

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myDB" pool-name="myDB" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.com:1521:sid</connection-url>
               <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
              <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>30</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>300</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool> 
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>120000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>        
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                    <datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Create folder in deployments, for example `c3p0Pool.sar`. Create `META-INF` folder `{JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/c3p0Pool.sar/META-INF`. Inside this folder create `jboss-service.xml` file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 jboss-service_7_0.xsd">
<mbean code="sar.C3P0PoolBinding" name="c3p0:service=c3p0Pool">
 <attribute name="JndiName">jdbc/myDB</attribute>
 <attribute name="JdbcUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.com:1521:sid</attribute>
 <attribute name="DriverClass">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</attribute>
 <attribute name="User">username</attribute>
 <attribute name="Password">password</attribute>
 <attribute name="MaxPoolSize">20</attribute>
 <attribute name="AcquireIncrement">0</attribute>
</mbean>
</server>
```

Create class and interface (classes names should be named correctly: ClassName and ClassNameMBean):

```
package sar;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource;

public class C3P0PoolBinding implements C3P0PoolBindingMBean {

    private String JndiName;
    private String JdbcUrl;
    private String DriverClass;
    private String User;
    private String Password;
    private int MaxPoolSize;
    private int AcquireIncrement;
    private C3P0PooledDataSource c3p0;

    public C3P0PoolBinding() {}

    public String getJndiName() {
        return this.JndiName;
    }

    public void setJndiName(String parameter) throws NamingException {
        this.JndiName = parameter;
    }

    public String getJdbcUrl() {
        return this.JdbcUrl;
    }

    public void setJdbcUrl(String jdbcUrl) throws NamingException {
        this.JdbcUrl = jdbcUrl;
    }

    public String getDriverClass() {
        return this.DriverClass;
    }

    public void setDriverClass(String driverClass) throws NamingException {
        this.DriverClass = driverClass;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.User;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) throws NamingException {
        this.User = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) throws NamingException {
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public int getMaxPoolSize() {
        return this.MaxPoolSize;
    }

    public void setMaxPoolSize(int maxPoolSize) throws NamingException {
        this.MaxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
    }

    public int getAcquireIncrement() {
        return this.AcquireIncrement;
    }

    public void setAcquireIncrement(int acquireIncrement) throws NamingException {
        this.AcquireIncrement = acquireIncrement;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        Logger.getLogger(C3P0PoolBinding.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Enabling c3p0 connection Pool");
        try {
            c3p0 = new C3P0PooledDataSource();
            c3p0.setJndiName(JndiName);
            c3p0.setJdbcUrl(JdbcUrl);
            c3p0.setDriverClass(DriverClass);
            c3p0.setUser(User);
            c3p0.setPassword(Password);
            c3p0.setMaxPoolSize(MaxPoolSize);
            c3p0.setAcquireIncrement(AcquireIncrement);
            c3p0.start();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        Logger.getLogger(C3P0PoolBinding.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Stopping c3p0 connection Pool");
        c3p0.destroy();
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
package sar;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public interface C3P0PoolBindingMBean {

    public String getJndiName();

    public void setJndiName(String JndiName) throws NamingException;

    public String getJdbcUrl();

    public void setJdbcUrl(String jdbcUrl) throws NamingException;

    public String getDriverClass();

    public void setDriverClass(String driverClass) throws NamingException;

    public String getUser();

    public void setUser(String user) throws NamingException;

    public String getPassword();

    public void setPassword(String password) throws NamingException;

    public int getMaxPoolSize();

    public void setMaxPoolSize(int maxPoolSize) throws NamingException;

    public int getAcquireIncrement();

    public void setAcquireIncrement(int acquireIncrement) throws NamingException;
}
```

Finnaly, create JAR file with these classes and place it to `{JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/c3p0Pool.sar/c3p0Jar.jar`

Now c3p0 pooling should work as expected.